# Frequent Disconnection and re-connection of web socket requests after deployment in the K8s

Tags: node.js, angularjs, kubernetes, websocket, socket.io

I am working on the development of a chat application using the `socket.io` library in the back end and `ngx-socket-io` in the front end. The chat functionality is working fine on the local environment and there is only one web socket connection in the network tab of the browser.

But when i deploy the code on the Kubernetes cluster I can see that the web socket connection does not persist longer and the previous web socket request is closed and new request is initiated i.e. the web socket connection is disconnecting and then re-connecting.

It is not persistent even on a single active pod or service in the Kubernetes cluster.

I want a single web socket connection to persist for longer duration, only then i can have the live chat working otherwise live chat ceases once a new web socket connection is initiated.
[image]

Comment: How do you access your pods? Via Ingress? Via Service IP? Directly via pod's IP?

Comment: It is accessed via Ingress. However i have tried to access the pods and service as well via port forwarding on my local machine.

Comment: which Ingress do you have - HaProxy, NGiNX?

Comment: We are using NGINX

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply following annotations for Ingress with websocket protocol. See example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3746):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 3600
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 3600
```

Comment: Does it require Nginx configuration changes also for upgrade header in the proxy pass ?

Comment: what do you mean by that? here is an example of Ingress for websocket connections https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/7045c03c021ce46b08cb3f41db0d76da#file-ingress-service-yaml

Comment: We have used angular as the frontend and we are using the NGINX as the webserver to host the angular code. So I am asking about the configuration on the Web server side to enable the websockets. I have used the above mentioned configuration for ingress but the result is still the same, the connection establishes and then disconnects after some time and the upgrade header is also happening properly. We have also tries without ingress it is not persistent.

Comment: Then it's not related to k8s but to configuration of your backup application

Comment: It works well when i run it on my local machine with Nginx having the default configuration. But when i deploy it in the kubernetes the connections are not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by using the traefik controller which is an advanced controller instead of nginx ingress controller.